# Как передать список объектов из БД?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Как передать список объектов из БД? Например, у меня есть модель `Книга` и я создал 5 книг. А еще у меня есть модель `Полка`, куда я хочу передать копии этих книг (т.е. чтобы при изменении книг на полке, сами книги, оригинальные, не менялись)

Пробовал так:

```
var books = db.Book.ToList().Select(c => new Book
{
    Author = c.Author,
    Text = c.Text
}).ToList();

    Shelf shelf = new Shelf();

    shelf.books_on_shelf = books;
```

Но при изменении `shelf.books_on_shelf` меняется и `db.Book`

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему у вас класс представляющий книгу довольно прост, поэтому перепишите свой код так:

```
var books = db.Book.ToList();

Shelf shelf = new Shelf();

shelf.books_on_shelf = books.Select(c => new Book
{
    Author = c.Author,
    Text = c.Text
}).ToList();
```

Comment: К сожалению проблема осталась. У меня при добавлении книг на полку, те же книги добавляются к "оригинальным". То есть Если у меня книга Пушкина и книга Толстого и я добавляю их на полку, то у меня становится две книги Толстого, две книги Пушкина в книгах и по книге на полке, которые я собственно и добавлял

Comment: @Adrian, немного непонятна логика того что вы хотите получить. Почему книга на полке не должна быть в полном перечне книг?

Comment: На самом деле у меня другая модель. Есть "Тест кейсы" и "Тестовые наборы". На страничке с кейсами список кейсов, на страничке наборов я могу добавить набор и выбрать для него кейсы. И вот выбранные кейсы добавляются на страничку самих кейсов, то есть дублируются

Comment: @Adrian, мне кажется, что у вас неправильная модель. Возможно, вам стоит в рамках отдельного вопроса описать что вы хотите и чтобы вам помогли составить модель. Как мне видится на данный момент вам необходима просто связь многие-ко-многим, плодить копии в любом случае неверно...

Comment: Буквально только что решил проблему. Поменял в модели Test_Suite тип Test_Case на аналогичный Test_Case2, и в методе при получении списка кейсов конвертирую их в Test_Case2